# Java Semaphore cause deadlock on multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, semaphore

should I take care of multithread problem when using Semaphore?
After my test seems some time Semaphore#release not cause acquire wake up even though there is enough permits.

Bottom is my test code .

1. Semaphore with 2 permits
2. thread-3 and thread-2 up first
3. thread-3 acquire a permit , wait on `lock` which will notify by thread-1
4. thread-2 acquire a permit, wait on `lock1` which will notify by thread-3
5. thread-1 start up ,sleep 30ms for thread-1 and thread-2 start up first
6. thread-1 notify `lock`, **acquire 2 permits**
7. thread-3 wake ,notify `lock1`,**`sleep(1)` sleep 1 ms for thread-2 acquire a permit first**,**release a permit**
8. thread-2 wake , **acquire a permit**, **then release a permit and release another permit**

it will cause deadlock at random iteration, and out put some log like this.

```
in 3, a = 2
in 2 ,a = 2
in in 2 lock 1, a = 0
in 1 , a = 0
acquire and release 3
in in 2 locked, a = 0
out 3 ,a  = 0
in 1 locked, a = 0
acquire and release 2
out 2
out 1 ,a = 2
--------------------------------------------------------------  0
in 2 ,a = 2
in 3, a = 1
in 1 , a = 0
in in 2 lock 1, a = 0
acquire and release 3
out 3 ,a  = 1 
//deadlock here
```

After thread-3 Semaphore release permit, doesn't cause thread-2 wake up, then thread-1 and thread-3 wait for acquire forever

**bleow is my test code**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

/**
 * Created by rqg on 6/10/17.
 */
public class WaitTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);

        final Object lock = new Object();
        final Object lock1 = new Object();
//        testSemaphore(semaphore, lock, lock1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            testSemaphore(semaphore, lock, lock1);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------  " + i);
        }
    }

    private static void testSemaphore(Semaphore semaphore, Object lock, Object lock1) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);

                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                    System.out.println("in 1 , a = " + semaphore.availablePermits());
                    semaphore.acquire(2);
                    System.out.println("in 1 locked, a = " + semaphore.availablePermits());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                semaphore.release(2);

                System.out.println("out 1 ,a = " + semaphore.availablePermits());
            }
        };


        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    System.out.println("in 2 ,a = " + semaphore.availablePermits());
                    semaphore.acquire();

                    synchronized (lock1) {
                        lock1.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.println("in in 2 lock 1, a = " + semaphore.availablePermits());
                    semaphore.acquire();
                    System.out.println("in in 2 locked, a = " + semaphore.availablePermits());
                    semaphore.release();

                    semaphore.release();

                    System.out.println("acquire and release 2");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("out 2");
            }
        };

        Thread t3 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("in 3, a = " + semaphore.availablePermits());
                    semaphore.acquire();

                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }

                    synchronized (lock1) {
                        lock1.notify();
                    }
                    sleep(1);

                    semaphore.release();

                    System.out.println("acquire and release 3");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("out 3 ,a  = " + semaphore.availablePermits());

            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();


        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
}
```

Here is my tread dump when deadlock happened

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` is used by `Semaphore` do some synchronize work. **It has FIFO property** , this cause Problem.

I have 2 permits , and after thread-3 release a permit , there is only one permit available, according to `Semaphore` FIFO acquire order, if My `thread-3 acquire(2)` happen before `thread-2 acquire(1)`, thread-3 will block forever.

I use Semaphore with `fair=false`, internal will init `NonfairSync` which `extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`.

below code cause Semaphore always flow FIFO acquire order.

```java
/**
 *java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#doAcquireSharedInterruptibly
*/
private void doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int arg)
    throws InterruptedException {
    final Node node = addWaiter(Node.SHARED);
    boolean failed = true;
    try {
        for (;;) {
            final Node p = node.predecessor();
            if (p == head) {
                int r = tryAcquireShared(arg);
                if (r >= 0) {
                    setHeadAndPropagate(node, r);
                    p.next = null; // help GC
                    failed = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                throw new InterruptedException();
        }
    } finally {
        if (failed)
            cancelAcquire(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Semaphore only keeps number of permits . From Semaphore docs:

> Conceptually, a semaphore maintains a set of  permits.  Each {@link
>   acquire} blocks if necessary until a permit is available, and then takes it.  Each {@link #release} adds a permit,  potentially
>   releasing a blocking acquirer.  However, no actual permit objects
>   are used; the {@code Semaphore} just  keeps a count of the number
>   available and acts accordingly.

I means that program should care of synchronization.

> Semaphores are often used to restrict the number of threads than can
>   access some (physical or logical) resource

Comment: Methods of Semaphore are not synchronized

Comment: if Semaphore is not thread safe , then Semaphore is useless. I don't understand why Semaphore is not thread safe and design for concurrent use case

Comment: Semaphore blocks if no permit is available. I think there is deadlock because at some time no thread can release permit.

Comment: release permit will wake up blocked thread, as my log,  I have a available permit ,but thread-2 doesn't wake up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146484/discussion-between-fantasy-rqg-and-jay-smith).

Answer (score 0):

You are wright the dead lock happening as release did not signal the park thread.
I found some bug reported for this
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7011859

Comment: I update my question ,and add thread dump after deadlock.
`thread_2` and `thread_1` wait on Semaphore#acquire . `lock` not cause the deadlock problem .